# Looking for help with this shipping report! The Case Syntax is throwing me for a loop

Tags: sql-server, ssms, case

So, the goal of this report is to get all orders that have been shipped in a month (October here). I was initially just using the 'PickedUpOn' field but soon found that there were instances where this value could be null so I was not generating a full population of shipments. In these instances, I want to pull the date from the kpo.loadtracking where the CheckCallName is 'PickedUp - Actual'. The current code is below and is giving me the following error:

> "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'CASE'"

This is my first time using the CASE statement so forgive me if this is an obvious answer.

```
SELECT 

LOAD.LoadNumber,lOAD.LoadId,CustomerName,OrderStatus,PickedUpOn, load.OriginEarliest, load.DestinationEarliest,CustomerRate,CarrierCost,Miles

FROM KPO.LOAD

left JOIN kpo.LoadExtension
on load.LoadId= LoadExtension.LoadId

LEFT JOIN kpo.Customer
on customer.CustomerId = load.CustomerID

LEFT JOIN kpo.LoadTracking
on LoadTracking.LoadId = Load.LoadId

CASE WHEN PickedUpOn IS NOT NULL

WHERE DATEDIFF("mm",getdate(),pickupon)=-2)
AND OrderStatus<>'VOID'

ELSE 

WHERE DATEDIFF("mm",getdate(),Loadtracking.KeypointStatusDate)=-2)
AND CheckCallName ='Pickup - Actual'
AND OrderStatus<>'VOID'

Order By CustomerName
```

Comment: You can't have a WHERE clause inside a CASE expression. It should be the other way around.

Comment: `WHERE DATEDIFF("mm",getdate(),pickupon)=-2)` - this is better expressed without applying a function to a column, this way if there is (or ever will be) a covering index with `pickupon` as the key, there is a chance it will get used. See [this recent answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/224329/1186) for an example of deriving the month range for two months ago, and [the slide deck and samples here](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/slides-demos-sqlintersection-2018/) for my presentation from yesterday on a bunch of date/time related topics.

Comment: Also, [please get out of the `"mm"` shorthand habit](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations). Just type `MONTH`!

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead.  As ypercube said, you can't use CASE like that.

```
SELECT LOAD.LoadNumber
    ,LOAD.LoadId
    ,CustomerName
    ,OrderStatus
    ,PickedUpOn
    ,LOAD.OriginEarliest
    ,LOAD.DestinationEarliest
    ,CustomerRate
    ,CarrierCost
    ,Miles
FROM KPO.LOAD
    LEFT JOIN kpo.LoadExtension ON LOAD.LoadId = LoadExtension.LoadId
    LEFT JOIN kpo.Customer ON customer.CustomerId = LOAD.CustomerID
    LEFT JOIN kpo.LoadTracking ON LoadTracking.LoadId = LOAD.LoadId 
WHERE ( PickedUpOn IS NOT NULL 
        AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, getdate(), pickupon) = - 2 
        AND OrderStatus <> 'VOID'
        )
    OR (    PickedUpOn IS NULL
            AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, getdate(), Loadtracking.KeypointStatusDate) = - 2 )
            AND CheckCallName = 'Pickup - Actual'
            AND OrderStatus <> 'VOID'
            )
ORDER BY CustomerName
```

You could also use COALESCE to handle when pickupon is NULL

```
DATEDIFF(MONTH, getdate(), COALESCE(pickupon, Loadtracking.KeypointStatusDate))
```